# python inheritance vs initializing with object

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, code-structure

Let us suppose that i have a file that has several tables in it. I want to read the content of the tables. Each table also has multiple sections in it. Let's say i defined the file object as follows (which is a very rough layout of my code):

```
from tables import TableA,TableB

class File(TableA,TableB):

   def __init__(self,filename):

      self.in_file_name=open(filename,'rb')
      self.record_bytes=self.in_bytes=''
      self.data={}

   def read(self):

       while 1:

          self._read_records():

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==1:
             self.read_section_A1()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==2:
             self.read_section_A2()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==3:
             self.read_section_B1()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==4:
             self.read_section_B2()

   def _read_record(self):

       self.in_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
       self.record_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
       self.in_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
```

Here is how the TableA and TableB classes are defined:

```
class TableA():

   def read_section_A1(self):

       self._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==5:
          self.data['A1']='TABLEA1DATA'

   def read_section_A2(self):

       self._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==6:
          self.data['A2']='TABLEA2DATA'

class TableB():

   def read_section_B1(self):
       self._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==6:
          self.data['B1']='TABLEB1DATA'

   def read_section_B2(self):
       self._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==7:
          self.data['B1']='TABLEB2DATA'
```

I understand that the above code just basically extends the File class. But i was wondering if it was a best practice approach (in terms of oop). As you can see, if i attempt to call the TableA or TableB class they will not work as they are not standalone. Furthermore, the inheritance does not seem to be ideal, since oftentimes, an object inherits from a more general class. In my application TableA and TableB are actually a subset of the file.

Here is something that I was considering doing:

```
from tables import TableA,TableB

class File():

   def __init__(self,filename):

      self.in_file_name=open(filename,'rb')
      self.record_bytes=self.in_bytes=''
      self.data={}

   def read(self):

       while 1:

          self._read_records():

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==1:
             TableA(self).read_section_A1()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==2:
             TableA(self).read_section_A2()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==3:
             TableB(self).read_section_B1()

          if unpackint(self.record_bytes)==4:
             TableB(self).read_section_B2()

   def _read_record(self):

       self.in_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
       self.record_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
       self.in_bytes=self.in_file.read(4)
```

And TableA and B would be defined as follows:

```
class TableA():

   def __init__(self,File):
       self.File=File

   def read_section_A1(self):

       self.File._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.File.record_bytes)==5:
          self.File.data['A1']='TABLEA1DATA'

   def read_section_A2(self):

       self.File._read_record()
       if unpackint(self.File.record_bytes)==6:
          self.File.data['A2']='TABLEA2DATA'
```

Is this the preferred methods? Is there any other way that i can improve the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship.  Is a File a Table?  No, a file has tables.  Your second approach is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, that was what i was thinking as well.